# How can I get Insightly API to work with python?

Tags: python, api, insightly

I apologize in advance for such a basic question. I've tried using the Insightly for Python github repo. The sample code is:

```
from insightly import Insightly
i = Insightly(apikey=my_api_key)
```

I tried this with my apikey and got a 401 error. IT verified that the account they gave me the API key for has all necessary permissions.

I also tried using python requests. The documentation says "The API key needs to be included as the Base64-encoded username, leaving the password blank."

My code is:

```
import requests 
r = requests.get('https://api.na1.insightly.com/v3.1/Contacts',auth=(my_api_key,''))
```

and this as well got a 401 error.

Is there a better way to access the Insightly API using python?

Comment: Did you manage to sort this out? I've basically arrived to the same point independently.